# How to let Skype start silently without welcome screen?

Tags: skype

I would like to let Skype start without welcome screen, everything what I need to see is a green icon of connected Skype.

What and where should I set to reach that?

I have checked to log-in automatically, but still there is an Skype logo on log-in time and Skype window stays open afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Select **Options** and check the "Start Skype minimised in the system tray" option.

Comment: funny, such simple, I have to watch more carefully. thanx.